# Erro Duplicate identifiers for rows Usando Spread

Tags: r

Estou querendo arrumar a base de dado do **FMI**, tudo deu certo, só que na hora de usar a função `spread()`, está dando este erro.

**Comando:**

```
weo <- weo2 %>%
spread(key= `WEO Subject Code`, value=valor)
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (8686, 8687), (17373, 17374), (26060, 
>       26061), (34747, 34748), (43434, 43435), (52121, 52122), (60808, 60809), 
>       (69495, 69496), (78182, 78183), (86869, 86870), (95556, 95557), (104243, 
>       104244), (112930, 112931), (121617, 121618), (130304, 130305), (138991, 
>       138992), (147678, 147679), (156365, 156366), (165052, 165053), (173739, 
>       173740), (182426, 182427), (191113, 191114), (199800, 199801), (208487, 
>       208488), (217174, 217175), (225861, 225862), (234548, 234549), (243235, 
>       243236), (251922, 251923), (260609, 260610), (269296, 269297), (277983, 
>       277984), (286670, 286671), (295357, 295358), (304044, 304045), (312731, 
>       312732), (321418, 321419), (330105, 330106), (338792, 338793), (347479, 
>       347480), (356166, 356167), (364853, 364854)

Comment: Infelizmente, a tua pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R, de modo que as pessoas que querem te ajudar consigam fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.